# absolute convergent but not uniform convergent

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Absolute and uniform convergence of $\sum _{n=1}^{n=\infty }2^{n}\sin \frac {1} {3^{n}z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123754/absolute-and-uniform-convergence-of-sum-n-1n-infty-2n-sin-frac-1)

I need to show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^k \sin\left(\frac{1}{3^k x}\right)$ is aboslutely convergent for $x$ nonzero but not uniformly convergent on $(\epsilon, \infty)$.  I have the absolute part but for the uniform I'm trying to show the tail $\sum_{k=n}^m 2^k \sin\left(\frac{1}{3^k x}\right)$ is less than $\epsilon$ for $n$ sufficiently large.  I can't see to create the bound.